# web page not available error

Tags: android

```
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
    }
}

WebView w=(WebView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.webView);
WebView.enablePlatformNotifications();
w.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
w. getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically (false);
w. getSettings().setPluginsEnabled (true);
w.loadUrl("http://www.agaraadhi.com");
w.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
```

I'm trying to load a web page into the web view.I get web page not available error.I can access the page from the default browser.I set the permission in manifest.But the below code works fine.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.agaraadhi.com");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Check if you are able to access the web  page from emulator browser. Also check the proxy settings in emulator.

Comment: I can access the page from emulator browser. Also this code Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.agaraadhi.com"); Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri); startActivity(intent); works properly.But m not able to load the page into webview.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />  

These two tags must be before application tag in manifest.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Web page not available"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23862486/web-page-not-available)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the permission `android.permission.INTERNET` enabled in AndroidManifest.xml? E.g.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

---

Regarding one of the comments above, I haven't heard of WebViews requiring the `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission, and have had them working without it, but perhaps the functionality is automatically used for something optional if available(?)