# "Web page not available"

Tags: java, android

The default Browser application on my HTC Hero v1.5 just keeps coming up with the standard "Web page not available" page when I try to display html page from  my android application

Comment: can you see the page in your browser?? is your internet active??

Comment: Did you add [INTERNET_PERMISSION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378607/what-permission-do-i-need-to-access-internet-from-an-android-application)?

Comment: my html file in assets folder so no required any  INTERNET_PERMISSION permission for access html file...

Comment: You need add the INTERNET_PERMISSION in your manifest file.

Comment: If it's local, some code would help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [web page not available error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160165/web-page-not-available-error)

Answer (score 1):

You need add the INTERNET permission in you Manifest file:

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

more info here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html